# Convert multiple point number to a single point double

Tags: java

My input is:

```
21.000.00
21,000.00

4.102.102.00
4,102,102.00
```

Output should be:

```
21000.00
21000.00

4102102.00
4102102.00
```

I just want to retain the last period because I pass this value to a `Double.valueOf(value)`

I can replace the commas with an empty string easily to get rid of it but the periods are tricky.

Whats the fastest method to get rid of the first periods and retain the last?

I'm solving this on Java/Android

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it appears to be a zero-effort requirements dump.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, or to clarify *precisely* where you are having difficulty, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: How to do know the last `.` is the decimal point? What if input is `21.000`? The input `21.000.00` is *corrupt*. It should have been `21.000,00`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your input would be in that format, but if that's the case, something like this would parse it:

```
  String s = "4.102.102.00";
  s = s.replaceAll(",", "");
  String s2 = "";
  int lastDot = s.lastIndexOf('.');
  if (lastDot >= 0) {
    s2 = s.substring(lastDot);
    s = s.substring(0, lastDot).replaceAll("\\.", "");
  }
  s = s + s2;
  System.out.println(s);
  System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(s));
```